# Error message "firefox doesn't work anymore"

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium Webdriver for Firefox (most recent version). Everytime I start my test, I'll get an error message from Windows itself saying Firefox crashed. When I hit the Force close-Button, the test starts as it should.

I am new to Eclipse and Selenium, but in debugger mode I didn't find the problematic code (So many threads running at the same time).. Haven't tried to find Windows log, but maybe some of you know the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced firefox crashes on Mac OS X when used Firefox 38 with selenium 2.45.

There are *compatibility issues* between the two. You have two options:

- downgrade Firefox to 35.0.1, [direct link](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/35.0/) (latest supported by 2.45)
- [upgrade your `selenium` language bindings](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to 2.46

Answer (score 0):

upgrade selenium version selenium-webdriver-2.46.1 (latest), it will solve your problem